# How do you update a database within asp.net MVC - is this the best way?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Following some excellent help from this forum, can anyone please confirm if this is the best way to update data in a database, in an MVC Controller, where multiple records/models are posted back at once?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ObjectivesEdit model)
{
    if (model.Objectives != null)
    {
        // model will have several records posted back - so loop through each one, and update the database
        foreach (var item in model.Objectives)
        {
            // find the database row
            Objective objective = db.objectives.Find(item.ID);

            // Set the database row to the posted values
            objective.objective = item.objective;
            objective.score = item.score;
            objective.possscore = item.possscore;
            objective.comments = item.comments;
        }
        // Save the changes to the database
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

The part I think probably has a better way of working is:

```
objective.objective = item.objective;
objective.score = item.score;
objective.possscore = item.possscore;
objective.comments = item.comments;
```

Can that be replaced with something more streamlined, or is that the way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than using lambda expressions such as:

```
var employees = data.Employees.Where(em => em.City.StartsWith("B")).ToList();
employees.ForEach(em => em.City = "ABC");
```

(above taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/0f014318-5259-43c7-8518-06948cec465e))

You would have to update records in a loop as you are currently doing it.  Note that the above is still a loop, but is executed internally (and looks a bit cleaner).

Comment: Not sure if there is a performance gain by using lambda... The only way to really speed up the update is by executing raw SQL as LINQ does not provide a way to update sets of records as of yet.

Another idea would be to use a stored procedure

Comment: Are SubmitChanges (as in the link you gave) and SaveChanges different, or do the same thing?

Comment: I have always used SaveChanges, and after a quick search it appears that they do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use repository pattern for updating or adding to database.

look at the link below

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/asp-net-mvc-using-repository-pattern-code-review

Comment: WOW, MVC is already a pattern and now we need to use another pattern to update the database. What ever happened to simplicity?

Comment: with the use of repository pattern you can have many benefits such as :
Duplicated queries and data-access patterns can be removed and refactored into the repository
Centralized data access which result in  
Greater separation of concerns which increases  both maintainability and readability
flexible and less coupled architecture

Comment: Sounds great but:
How does a repository pattern differentiate to a single database which holds all of its queries in stored procedures? How does Greater separation of Concerns differentiate from n-tier architecture?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue i see with your code is that you could potentially hit the database for every record that is returned. Also if your holding the entire object on the form the mapping isn't completely necessary

So you would want to query all necessary objectcs in one query

```
var Objectives = db.Objectives.where(o => model.Objectives.select(ob => ob.ID).Contains(o.ID));
```

this will bring back all the Objectives from the database that have been posted to the controller action.

then inside your foreach change

```
Objective objective = db.objectives.Find(item.ID);
```

to

```
Objective objective = Objectives.First(o => o.ID == item.ID);
```

Then continue your mapping

Just always try and minimize your trips to the database

Comment: Hi - I got an error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'EditorTemplateDemo.Models.Objective'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. on this line: Objective objective = Objectives.First(o => o.ID == item.ID);  Do you know what may be wrong?  thank you, Mark

Comment: I think something strange is happening with var Objectives = db.Objectives.where(o => model.Objectives.select(ob => ob.ID).Contains(o.ID)); though i can't really figure out what is wrong with it.